# Defer Parsing of "createjs.min.js" not working

Tags: javascript

I made an animation using  Adobe Animate and embedded it in a html-widget on the website, while test.html and createjs.min.js are stored *locally*.

html in the widget looks like this:

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts" src="https://example.com/test.html" width="678" height="678"></iframe>
```

the "test.html" starts

```
<!-- write your code here -->
<script src="createjs.min.js"></script>
<script>
var createjs,AdobeAn;!function(t,e){var n,i={},o={},s={};i.webFontTxtInst={};var a=0,r=0,l=[],c=......
```

now I realize, that this is ***not loaded defer***. although all other iframes are loaded defer. If I add defer to the "test.html" like this...

```
<!-- write your code here -->
<script defer src="createjs.min.js"></script>
<script>
var createjs,AdobeAn;!function(t,e){var n,i={},o={},s={};i.webFontTxtInst={};var a=0,r=0,l=[],c=......
```

the animation is not loading anymore (only the background color can be seen).

Any clues how to solve this?

This is how it looks if the animation runs ;-)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: nobody #help, please!

Comment: hmmm, still no solution